Getting 0 as result of request to v1/email/messages/?type=notSent
We are trying to use the Marketing Cloud endpoint to get Transactional Emails that were not sent to recipients, using this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_transactional_messaging_email/getMessagesNotSent.html
We have enabled the Collection from Salesforce Developers in Postman to set it up, only adding our own credentials and endpoint. We are getting access tokens as normal and we are seeing a 200 as a response from the not Sent API, but the results are zero:
{
    "requestId": "023ba535-5da6-48ef-8a6f-c62dc476d639",
    "lastEventID": 0,
    "messages": [],
    "count": 0,
    "pageSize": 50
}

We are seeing emails that are not sent from the Event notification set-up we have and are wondering why they do not show up in this API call.
Anyone who can help?

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. We are seeing emails that are not sent from the Event notification set-up - including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
